# Knockout validation on a dropdown using a computed observable triggers immediately

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a problem very similar to [Knockout Validation evaluates immediately on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691109/knockout-validation-evaluates-immediately-on-load) only the solution presented there doesn't work for me, because I cannot initialize the observable with "" as it is a computed observable with logic in it.

I also tried binding it to the dropdown with:

```
value: computedObservable()
```

or:

```
value: function(){computedObservable}
```

or:

```
value: function(){computedObservable}()
```

instead of:

```
value: computedObservable
```

The observable itself is defined as:

```
viewModel.computedObservable = ko.pureComputed({
    write: function (value) {
        viewModel.observable(value);
    },
    read: function () {
        return viewModel.isObservableComputed() ? viewModel.existingModel().observable() : viewModel.observable();
    }
}).extend({ required: true });
```

*How do I prevent validation on load (it is shown in a bootstrap modal) yet still trigger the validation on a save?*

Comment: Does `ko.validation.init({ messagesOnModified: true })` help out?

Comment: @user3297291 no, while this was set to false (default = true), setting it to true didn't help :(

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but for me the validation with the option works as intended. https://jsfiddle.net/5r1u154z/ Can you update this fiddle to show what happens in your situation?

Comment: @user3297291 I think this would be close: https://jsfiddle.net/5r1u154z/1/

Comment: Still seems to work? https://jsfiddle.net/5r1u154z/2/ (Did you try switching between the two option objects?)

Comment: @user3297291 I see that you changed the messagesOnModified property. However outside of the fiddle it doesn't work. My temporary fix is checking in onlyIf if another (required) field is empty or not.

Comment: It's hard for me to help you out if you can't somehow reproduce your issue. The fiddle I provided shows how the option that is specifically designed to solve these kind of problems works. If it doesn't for you, there's probably something else going on in code you haven't shown. I'd suggest you either refactor some stuff in your own code until it works as the example, or include a _non-working repro_ in your question.

Comment: @user3297291 I would if I knew what other factors come into play here. It is a complex project.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution was to use conditional validation and set it to false initially and check another (required) field in the onlyIf, so this field only becomes required when the other has a value.

Better solutions are still very much welcome.